# unauthorized: authentication required while pulling sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.7.1

Tags: docker

unauthorized: authentication required while pulling sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.7.1

[sequenceiq/hadoop-docker:2.7.1](https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/tags) is in docker registry. And using registry-mirrors: https://dockerhub.azk8s.cn in local Docker Engine config. It's able to pull other images. Did the error happen due to certain issues in my PC? what's the possible solution?

Environment:
Windows 10 Home
Docker desktop 2.2.0.4

Update:
Trying with another mirror again at home works.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a private docker registry. You need to authenticate yourself against that registry. Please run the below `login` command on your PC.

```
docker login -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD dockerhub.azk8s.cn
```

and then try to pull the image again.

Comment: dockerhub.azk8s.cn it's a `public` mirror of Docker Hub, not a private registry.